# How Spring is integrated with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I know how to configure Spring with hibernate.

But my question is how spring and hibernate integrate and how it works.

Below is the code that I used to create Spring + Hibernate application.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And this sessionFactory bean is injected in the java code,

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
public class DAOSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport {

@Autowired
public void createSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

As you can see that, Session Factory that I created with is associated with spring package but in code it is using hibernate package.

PS: I know HibernateDaoSupport is deprecated and this is just for understanding how both framework works.

Thanks Gimby for the link.[JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html)

Comment: There is a difference, the spring class is a factory, that creates instances of the Hibernate class.

Comment: Spring is used as an IoC, it injects SessionFactory in Hibernate, As you shown there is sessionFactory created by Spring context, not by yourself.

Comment: @mlewandowski: But that sessionFactory belongs to spring package.

Comment: @Lathy class named AbstractSessionFactoryBean super class of LocalSessionFactoryBean (which is the super class of AnnotationSessionFactoryBean) has a variable of type org.hibernate.SessionFactory and all the properties related to hiberate are stored in the LocalSessionFactoryBean. Also,  spring-orm.jar( which contains mentioned FactoryBean suffixed classes) has a dependency on hibernate-core.jar

Answer (score 2):

Spring's `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` (as well as `LocalSessionFactoryBean`) implements interface called `FactoryBean`. It has special method called `Object getObject()`.

Whenever Spring sees, that you use the implemention of `FactoryBean` interface, it invokes `Object getObject()` method instead of creating the instance of the class itself.

In this case, `SessionFactory` object will be returned by the method call.

To be more specific, `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` implements `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>` which in fact return `SessionFactory` object so it can be injected in Hibernate.

Comment: Perhaps add a link to the javadoc which backs up what you explain: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html